# HTML/JavaScript: How can I round off the values in an input type=number having a read-only option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I cannot find a solution on how to round off the values in my input type=number having a read-only option.

HTML code for table:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="">
        <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
            <td style="text-align: center; width: 316px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);" rowspan="2"><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;">​</span><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;"><b>FUNCTION NAME</b></span><b><br></b></td>
            <td style="text-align: center; width: 316px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);" rowspan="2"><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;">​</span><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;"><b>ORGANIZATIONAL OUTCOMES/KEY RESULTS AREA</b></span><b><br></b></td>
            <td style="text-align: center; width: 341px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);" rowspan="2"><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;"><b>QUALITY + OBJECTIVES</b></span><b><br></b><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;"><b>&nbsp;(TARGETS + MEASURES)</b></span></td>
            <td style="text-align: center; width: 437px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);" rowspan="2"><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;"><b>ACTUAL ACCOMPLISHMENTS</b></span></td>
            <td style="text-align: center; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);" colspan="4"><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;"><b>RATING</b></span></td>
            <td style="text-align: center; width: 366px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);" rowspan="2"><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;"><b>REMARKS</b></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
            <td style="text-align: center; width: 44px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);"><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;"><b>Q</b></span></td>
            <td style="text-align: center; width: 49px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);"><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;"><b>E</b></span></td>
            <td style="text-align: center; width: 44px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);"><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;"><b>T</b></span></td>
            <td style="text-align: center; width: 47px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);"><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;"><b>A</b></span></td>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        @foreach($ipcrcsassocp as $row)
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$row->form_id}}" name="form_id[]">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$row->function_name}}" name="function_name[]">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$row->id}}" name="mfo_id[]">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left; width: 316px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);" rowspan="0">{!! $row->function_name !!}</td>
                <td style="text-align: left; width: 316px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);" rowspan="0">{!! $row->mfo_desc !!}</td>
                <td style="text-align: left; width: 341px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);" rowspan="0">{!! $row->success_indicator_desc !!}</td>
                <td style="text-align: left; width: 437px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);" rowspan="0">{!! $row->actual_accomplishment_desc !!}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                    <td rowspan="0" style="text-align: center; border-top: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-right: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-bottom: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-image: initial; border-left: none; background: white; padding: 0.6pt;">
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <select name="Q[]" class="form-control form-control-sm q-value" style="width: 50px">
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="0" style="text-align: center; border-top: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-right: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-bottom: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-image: initial; border-left: none; background: white; padding: 0.6pt;">
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <select name="E[]" class="form-control form-control-sm e-value" style="width: 50px">
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="0" style="text-align: center; border-top: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-right: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-bottom: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-image: initial; border-left: none; background: white; padding: 0.6pt;">
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <select name="T[]" class="form-control form-control-sm t-value" style="width: 50px">
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="0" style="text-align: center; border-top: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-right: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-bottom: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-image: initial; border-left: none; background: white; padding: 0.6pt;">
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                        @if($row->function_name == 'Core Functions')
                                <input type="number" oninput="setFourNumberDecimal(this)" class="form-control form-control-sm a-value-core" name="A[]" style="width: 50px" readonly>
                            @elseif($row->function_name == 'Support Functions')
                                <input type="number" oninput="setFourNumberDecimal(this)" class="form-control form-control-sm a-value-support" name="A[]" style="width: 50px" readonly>
                            @endif
                            @if($row->function_name == 'Research and Extension Services')
                                <input type="number" oninput="setFourNumberDecimal(this)" class="form-control form-control-sm a-value-research" name="A[]" style="width: 50px" readonly>
                            @endif

                        </div>
                    </td>

                    <td style="text-align: center; width: 316px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);" rowspan="0">{!! $row->remarks !!}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            @endforeach
    </table>
```

Function:

```
function setFourNumberDecimal(el) {
        el.value = parseFloat(el.value).toFixed(4);
    };
```

The value in the inputs are also being computed by a Jquery function so I inserted the setFourNumberDecimal() inside of it.

```
               //COMPUTE THE AVERAGE PER ROW
    $(".q-value, .e-value, .t-value").change(function(){
        let currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
        let EValue = parseFloat(currentRow.find('.e-value').val());
        let QValue = parseFloat(currentRow.find('.q-value').val());
        let TValue = parseFloat(currentRow.find('.t-value').val());
        currentRow.find('.a-value-core').val((EValue  + QValue + TValue ) / 3);
        currentRow.find('.a-value-support').val((EValue  + QValue + TValue ) / 3);
        currentRow.find('.a-value-research').val((EValue  + QValue + TValue ) / 3);

        setFourNumberDecimal();
         computeAvg();
         computeWeightedScore();
    });
```

The expected output should round off the values up to 4 decimal places in the input types.

Comment: as your field is readonly how you are going to put value in it?your round off function is working well but because your readonly field  onchange event not fired.so you have to format value before put into the field or call roundfunction on any other event which can trigger

Comment: Can you share the table html as well here?

Comment: try oninput instead

Comment: @ihorbond i tried, unfortunately did not work.

Comment: @HiteshTripathi The function still not worked, I already removed the readonly.

Comment: @JALO-JusAnotherLivngOrganism The table html cannot be inserted as comment sir.

Comment: @EdwarddelRosario I meant please update the question with the <table> content of your html.

Comment: ok the html have many codes since it is an output from roosterjs website. ill update it asap.

Comment: I see. jquery doc https://api.jquery.com/val/ mentions: .Setting values using this method (or using the native value property) does not cause the dispatch of the change event. For this reason, the relevant event handlers will not be executed. If you want to execute them, you should call .trigger( "change" ) after setting the value.

Comment: @ihorbond It works perfectly. I will post an answer for this one!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step-by-step on how my question resolved.

1. Create a function inside a script tag

```
function setFourNumberDecimal(el) {
  el.value = parseFloat(el.value).toFixed(4);
};
```

2. Create a Jquery script that uses a .trigger function and call the function created by `setFourNumberDecimal` as explained by @ihorbond in the comments section

```
$(".a-value-core, .a-value-support, .a-value-research, #core-total-average, #support-total-average, #research-total-average, #total-weighted-score").trigger("change")
    setFourNumberDecimal();
```

3. Then add this inside the input element

```
onchange="setFourNumberDecimal(this)"
```